# Python's psutil doesn't report correct process status

Tags: python, psutil

I'm using the following code to check if a process is running:

```
import time
import psutil

def isRunning(name):
    for process in psutil.process_iter():
        if name in process.name() and process.status() == psutil.STATUS_RUNNING:
            print(process.name(), process.status(), flush=True)
            return True
    return False

while isRunning("chrome.exe"):
    print("Chrome is running", flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

This code runs forever, even after closing chrome (I've checked the processes list to make sure there is is not hangig...). I'm running this on Window 10, Python 3.7.7 and psutil version 5.7.0

Is there a way to force clear psutil cache?

Comment: Try printing `process.pid` and then looking up that PID in the Task Manager to see what process it thinks it is.

Comment: Also, why are you using `in` instead of `==`? If you have a processed named `helpchrome.exe` it will match the test.